# Accessing the value from another class to do the calculation within a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing a web application using C# and MVC5. How can I use the value from another class to do the calculation within a controller? For example, I have two classes: Product and Calculation. Product class looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }       
}
```

Calculation class looks like this:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

So, when selecting product from the combobox, I want the method to use price of the selected product (which is property of the class Product) and Quantity(which is property of the class Calculation) to calculate TotalPrice. So, in my CalculationController, method Create looks like this:

```
// GET: Calculation/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "ProductName");
        return View();
    }

// POST: Calculation/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductId,Quantity,TotalPrice")] Calculation calculation)
    {


        if (calculation.TotalPrice == null)

        {

// So this part doesn’t work because it can’t access the value of ProductPrice property from another class.
            calculation.TotalPrice = product.ProductPrice * Quantitiy;

            db.Calculations.Add(calculation);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        ViewBag.ProductId = new SelectList(db.Products, "Id", "ProductName", calculation.ProductId);
        return View(calculation);
    }
```

I realize I need to initialize it in order to use the value from another class, but can someone please try to explain exactly how to do it on this example, because I'm constantly doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can instantiate Product from db using productID

Comment: Can you show me how exactly to do so on this example so I can understand better? Thank you.

Comment: Something like that: 
  var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ProductId);

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your code you're using Entity Framework, and lazy loading a Product property into your Calculation class (by the use of the virtual keyword). That will make it available the first time you access it.

But your problem is that you should access it as a property of that Calculation, i.e.

```
calculation.TotalPrice = calculation.Product.ProductPrice * Quantitiy;
```

As you could probably see you should avoid a null exception accessing that product price, so you should be sure (and/or make a null check) that the Product property for your calculation has been properly initialized.

For initialiazing it you should do before accesing it:

```
calculation.ProductId = productId //The one you're getting in the post
```

As this ProductId property is the let's say "foreign key" as stands on how EF works with these navigation properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way of accessing the property actually make sense.
However, I'm still not sure about the initializing part. I really tried a bunch of ways of doing this and I still don't understand. I would appretiate more detailed explenation of how exactly to write and place that code.